# What's the different with titles?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I would like to add title to my UIViewController:

I have tried

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.title
self.navigationController.title
self.title
```

Sometimes, solution 1 work, sometimes solution 2 work, sometimes solution 3 works.

Can any expert tell me the different between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`title` is a property of `UIViewController`.

> A localized string that represents the view this controller manages.
>   Set the title to a human-readable string that describes the view. If
>   the view controller has a valid navigation item or tab-bar item,
>   assigning a value to this property updates the title text in those
>   objects.

---

`self.navigationController` is a `UINavigationController` that manages the stack of viewControllers that your `viewController` is in.  `UINavigationController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, so `self.navigationController.title` is the `title` of the `UINavigationController`.

---

`self.navigationItem.title`:

> The navigation item’s title displayed in the center of the navigation
>   bar. The default value is nil. When the receiver is on the navigation
>   item stack and is second from the top—in other words, its view
>   controller manages the views that the user would navigate back to—the
>   value in this property is used for the back button on the top-most
>   navigation bar. If the value of this property is nil, the system uses
>   the string “Back” as the text of the back button.

---

So, in practice, you should set the `title` of your `ViewController`s.  iOS will copy this title to the navigation item or tab bar item and display this title on the *Navigation Bar* if your `ViewController` is managed by a `UINavigationController`, it will use that text for the *Back Button* when you push to another `ViewController`, and it will display it in the tab bar if your `ViewController` is managed by a `UITabBarController`.

Answer (score 3):

I create a demo to explain them：

[image]

You see, my `vc1` is yellow-gray `color` embed in a `navigation controller`,my `vc2` is light-green `color` embed in a `navigation controller` too, the two `navigation controller` is all manage by a `tabbar controller` .

In `ViewController.swift`(it is `vc1`), if I set `self.title`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "vc1's title"  
    }

}
```

In `ViewController2.swift`(it is `vc2`):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "vc2's title"
    }

}
```

The result is the `tabbar title` and `navigation title` all set:

> [image]

If I set `self.navigationController?.title`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // self.title = "vc1's title"

        self.navigationController?.title = "vc1's nav title"

    }
}
```

The result is `tabbar title` is set:

> [image: the result]

If I set `self.navigationItem.title`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // self.title = "vc1's title"

        //self.navigationController?.title = "vc1's nav title"

        self.navigationItem.title = "vc1's navItem title"
    }
}
```

The result is `navigation title` is set:

> [image]

Comment: Did you try self.navigationController.navigationItem.title?

Comment: I know it works as your demo, I want to know the root cause of this, then I can decide which one to use in my future development.